# C# variant of Win32's PdhGetFormattedCounterArray?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I want to use the '*' to collect performance counter data (max cpu core usage, disk usage etc.).

Is there a C# equivalent to PdhGetFormattedCounterArray?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pdh/nf-pdh-pdhgetformattedcounterarraya

Maybe I also need a C# substitute for PdhAddEnglishCounter.

Update:

Tx.Windows seems the way to go. However, it's limiting on how the Win32 api gets used. Also, it seems rather buggy and unnecessarily stringent. Looks like C# has pretty much the same issues as Java. Guess I'll revert to C/C++ then.

Comment: This project defines some of these: https://github.com/microsoft/Tx eg: https://github.com/microsoft/Tx/blob/master/Source/Tx.Windows/PerfCounters/PdhNativeMethods.cs

Comment: I take it you are already familiar with the .NET `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` classes ?

Comment: In particular, `PerformanceCounterCategory.ReadCategory()` looks related to what you want -- it reads all counters simultaneously in a single category.

Comment: @BenVoigt what would be the correct category name for the cpu cores or disks? Do you have any example?

Comment: Use `perfmon.exe` to see what performance counters are available on your system and pick which ones you want.  "Processor Information" and "LogicalDisk" look like good categories to use.

Comment: I have it working in c++/PDH. The counters are correct.